# Eclipse working with multiple projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, multiple-projects

I have two projects written in C++. Suppose that the projects are named first and second, the first being the base project, the second project has addons for the first so when I build and install the second project, it just adds to the functionality of the first.

I created two separate Makefile projects 'first' and 'second' and I am able to build both of them separately.

My problem is that I am not able to link the binaries generated in the 'first' as the base binaries for the 'second'. I tried searching for similar questions on stackoverflow but I did not get any idea on how to link binaries generated in the 'first' to 'second', any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if I need to reframe my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GCC, and read the [reference for linker options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) you will notice to options for linking with external libraries:

- `-L<directory>`

  This option tells the linker to add `<directory>` to the library search path. In other words, it tells the linker where to find library files.
- `-l<name-of-lib>`

  This option tells the linker to link with a library. Libraries in POSIX environments (Linux, OSX, Windows using Cygwin or MinGW) are named like `libname-of-lib.a`, but with the `-l` option you don't need to use the `lib` prefix or the `.a` extension. Also note that in the option `-l`, that is the small letter L (not capital i or the digit 1).

To summarise: To link with a library from another directory you link like this:

```
$ gcc <other flags> <object files> -o <executable> -L<directory> -l<library>
```

In your case you should for the `-L` option specify the directory where the library for `project1` is, and for the `-l` option you pass the basic name of the library.

---

If on the other hand you don't turn `project1` into a library, and want to link with its object files directly, that's fine too:

```
$ gcc <flags> <object files of project1> <object files of project2> -o <executable>
```

The object files can of course be full or relative paths. For example, if you have the following directory structure:

```
/
`-- home
    `-- user
        `-- myproject
            |-- project1
            `-- project2
```

Then in if you are in the `project2` directory you can access object files from `project1` like

```
../project1/objectfile.o
```

---

All of this can of course be placed in a Makefile.

Comment: Thank you Joachim, this was helpful indeed :)